# Обработка bootstrap multiple select

Tags: php, html

Пользуюсь [вот этим](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/) скриптом.

А точнее на странице стоит `multiple select` со следующим кодом:

```
<select name="buu[]" class="selectpicker" multiple title="Можно выбрать несколько">
  <option>Первое</option>
  <option>Второе</option>
  <option>третье</option>
  <option>четворое</option>
</select>
```

На php пишу такой код:

```
foreach ($_POST['buu'] as $selectedOption)
echo $selectedOption."\n";
```

При выводе на браузер нормально показывает а вот если хочу занести его в базу то в mysql попадает только последнее значение выбранных элементов

В чем может быть причина ?

Comment: $selectedOption = Trim(stripslashes(implode(", ", $_POST['buu'])));

Comment: @soledar10, а зачем эта `stripslashes()` функция здесь?

Comment: @Visman - копировал с проекта - можно и без stripslashes()

Comment: soledar10, спасибо заработало.

Comment: Visman, а это необязательно ставить там ? stripslashes ?

Comment: stripslashes -  Удаляет экранирование символов, произведенное функцией addslashes()

Comment: soledar10 47 , спасибо Вам ещё раз за пояснение. Как раз читал про эту функцию ! буду в дальнейшем знать

Comment: пример работы stripslashes() - https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_stripslashes